# Fork function with 2 integers

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to understand how the fork() function works for my class of operating systems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPUqB.png)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, height, width;
    if (argc!= 3) exit(0);
    height = atoi(argv[1]); /* height */
    width = atoi(argv[2]); /* width */   
    pid_t t;
    
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
t=fork();
for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
if(j==width-1){
if(t!=0){
      break;
      }
//break;
} else if (t==0){
//continue;
}}}
    printf("I´m father %d and my child is %d\n", getppid(), getpid());
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

this is what I get when height=4 and width=3.

```
I am the father  3182 y mi hijo es 3184 and my t value = 3190
I am the father  3180 and my child is 3181 and my t value = 3191
I am the father  2008 and my child is 3180 and my t value = 3186
I am the father  3180 and my child is 3182 and my t value = 3187
I am the father  3181 and my child is 3188 and my t value = 3192
I am the father  3180 and my child is 3183 and my t value = 3189
I am the father  3181 and my child is 3185 and my t value = 3194
I am the father  3185 and my child is 3193 and my t value = 3195
I am the father  3180 and my child is 3182 and my t value = 3187
I am the father  3180 and my child is 3181 and my t value = 3191
I am the father  2008 and my child is 3180 and my t value = 3186
I am the father  3181 and my child is 3185 and my t value = 3194
I am the father  2008 and my child is 3180 and my t value = 3186
I am the father  3180 and my child is 3181 and my t value = 3191
I am the father  2008 and my child is 3180 and my t value = 3186
```

The online course teacher published a message with a hint that I tried to follow, “The case is that the tree will go down x=height levels starting from the initial process, and the first child of each level will have y=width children, except in the last level where there will be (witdh -1) children”
I am 100% sure that there must be 2 for loops, an outer loop for height and an inner loop for width. All the children come out of the two loops and terminate after being created, except the last one, i.e. when j == width - 1, which continues with another repetition of the outer loop (height). Not having any guidance and clue is something.
Thanks.

I am very rookie in terms of the use of fork so if anyone could help me to un
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by having them print their number.

Comment: @Jorge Pulido Lozano - You still are _100% sure that there must be 2 for loops, an outer loop for height and an inner loop for width_ even after Chris Dodd wrote: _To create a 2D grid of processes like you describe, you'll need a second loop, but it should_ not _be nested_?

Answer (score 0):

A `break;` statement is an unconditional jump out of the containing loop.  So the (first) `break;` in your inner loop will terminate the inner loop (in the first iteration), and none of the code after it in the loop will ever execute.  So your forking loop is exactly equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    fork();
}
```

The inner loop never gets to the increment and second iteration, so might as well not exist.  The `t` value is never used anywhere so might as well not exist.

This kind of loop will end up generating 2<sup>height</sup> processes, including the original parent.  Each iteration through the loop all the processes created so far will fork, doubling the total number of processes.

---

To create n processes, the easiest way is with a loop of n times that forks and then `break;` in one of the two processes (either just the parent or just the child.  Something like:

```
for (i = 1; i < height; i++)   // starting at 1 as we want to count the existing parent process
    if (fork() == 0) break;
```

Here the parent will create one child and then break out of the loop and each child will create one more child and then break, and the last child will complete the loop normally (and not create a child).

To create a 2D grid of processes like you describe, you'll need a second loop, but it should *not* be nested.  Once you've created the first column in your picture, each process should create a single row:

```
for (i = 1; i < width; i++)
    if (fork() > 0) break;
```

Here the "parent" process (the original parent or any of the children created in the first loop) will create all the children directly -- no child in any column other than the first will create any children.

Note that for cleanliness, you should check if `fork()` ever fails (returns -1), though most of the time all you can do is report the error.

Comment: Hi Dodd, thanks for your answer. 
I have been triying to find the answer to my problem but there is still some issues about loops and fork that I don´t understand at all.
I remade the original question to clarify it more.